# tapestry 5.4 list all images from webapp folder

Tags: java, tapestry

My problem is, that I want to list all the images what is located
*project/src/main/webapp/images*

I know if I know the image(s) name(s) I can make an URL like this:

```
assetSource.getContextAsset(IMAGESLOCATION + imageName, currentLocale).toClientURL();
```

But what if I dont know all the images name?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web app (and tapestry as well) doesn't know/care about absolute path of files, as it could be deployed anywhere. 
You can get absolute path of some file by calling getRealPath of HttpServletRequest.

```
    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    ...
    // get root folder of webapp
    String root = request.getRealPath("/");
    // get abs path from any relative path
    String abs = root + '/' + relPath;
```

getRealPath of HttpServletRequest is deprecated, it's recommended to use ServletContext.getRealPath instead but it's not so easy to get ServletContext.

I prefer to use WebApplicationInitializer implementation

```
    public class AbstractWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Here we store ServletContext in some global static variable
        Global.servletContext = servletContext;
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need the ability to read files in a given folder. Here's some very basic code that will iterate through all of the files in a folder:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
  // else, it's a directory
}
```

All of the imports should be from the `java.io` [package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html).

Comment: Hello!

Thanks @Dusko for the response. I wrote a similar code, like yours, but the main problem that the getContextAsset can handle the relative path, but can't transform absolute. e.g. when i do this:
  `String path = assetSource.getContextAsset(IMAGESLOCATION + imageName, currentLocale).getResource().getFolder();
  File file = new File(path);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(file.list()));`
I got null, but the picture and the folder exist.